# Microdata: Why does Google demand location for an event that is at a venue?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have the following microdata HTML code:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PerformingArtsTheater">
    <h2  itemprop="name">The Old Vic</h2>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TheaterEvent" itemprop="http://schema.org/event">
        <h3 itemprop="name">Endgame</h3>
       <div itemprop="startDate">2020-01-27</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I.e. : A `PerformingArtsTheater` called "The Old Vic" has an event, the `TheaterEvent` called "Endgame".

When an event is at a `PerformingArtsTheater`, which is a `Place`, I would think that is is obvious that the `TheaterEvent`'s location is that same `PerformingArtsTheater`` ?

But Google's [Structured Data Test Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) finds an error in the `TheaterEvent`: "A value for the location field is required.".

How come? Wouldn't a `location` field here be redundant at best, and a contradiction at worst?

(Like "February at The Old Vic: Endgame by Samuel Beckett at The Old Vic.")

Is there a way to please Gogle here, without introducing redundancy?

Answer (score 1):

`Thing > Event > TheaterEvent`

**[TheaterEvent](https://schema.org/TheaterEvent)** (Theater performance.) - `location` property **expected Type** `place` or **more** specific object like [PerformingArtsTheater](https://schema.org/PerformingArtsTheater):

```
Thing > Place > CivicStructure > PerformingArtsTheater
```

In your case the PerformingArtsTheater is `The Old Vic` - the correct data structure outline:

#### Location (Required property for event snippet)

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event

```
<div itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PerformingArtsTheater">
  <span itemprop="name">Theater name</span>
  <meta itemprop="address" content="London, UK"/>
</div>
```

[image]

#### Put the location as PerformingArtsTheater property (Nested object)

```
<section itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/TheaterEvent">
  <h2  itemprop="name">Event Name</h2>
  <div itemprop="startDate">2020-01-27</div>
  <address itemprop="location" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PerformingArtsTheater">
    <p itemprop="name" content="Theater name">Theater name</p>
    <meta itemprop="address" content="Bennelong Point, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia"/>
  </address>
</section>
```

**Result ==> No errors:**

[image]

Google snippet preview (Add image, description and so on)
[image]

By the way this is great example of nesting schema.org objects.

Comment: Thank you for a useful link! And Google's interpretation must for all practical purposes be regarded as correct. (Just like Microsoft's interpretation of HTML back in IE6 days.)

I stick to my rant, though: It is obvious that an event inside the location Carthago, has Carthago as its location.